# Show a modal when a link or text is clicked using JAVASCRIPT only.

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been trying to figure this out since I am a noob when it comes to Javascript.

Here's the [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6ZNtc/2/) I've been working on.

Right now, If you click the "Activate Modal" link, nothing shows yet, but when you change the a link code and use the href="#modal" , the modal/pop-up will show. Now, what I want to do is to make the modal appear without using a link, is it possible to just click on a word and use an onClick event or something ? Can you guys guide me through how it would work?

Here's the modal code:

```
 <div id="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="headerarticle">

            <a href="#" class="btn">X</a>

            <h2>Learn</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="copy">
            <div class="article-image"><img src="images/slow-moving-stock.png"></div>
            <div class="article-word">autem</div>
            <div class="article-def">Nam a justo vulputate, interdum quam nec, auctor turpis. Nulla dapibus, lectus a aliquet lacinia, turpis dui feugiat dolor</div>
            <div class="article-samp">Donec faucibus pulvinar magna, vel convallis ipsum interdum at.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `just click on a word` : which word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rewrite the code for anchor:

```
<a href="#" onclick="showModal();return false;" class="btn go">
```

Then you need to update the **showModal** function in your js file:

```
function showModal(){
    var modal = document.getElementById('modal');
    modal.style.display = 'block';
}
```

P.s. Why you dont use jQuery? It's has a very simplified syntax, shorter and easy to use
p.p.s. You can use onclick almost everywhere, except the following tags: `<base>, <bdo>, <br>, <head>, <html>, <iframe>, <meta>, <param>, <script>, <style>, <title>`

Comment: I am not allowed to rewrite the code for the anchor, do you have any other ways? @n1kkou

Comment: var trigger = document.getElementsByClassName('go')[0];
trigger.onclick = function(){
    var modal = document.getElementById('modal');
    modal.style.display = 'block';
};   p.s. i'm learning to format inline code on comments ^^

Comment: I also updated you css styles for the modal #modal:  http://jsfiddle.net/6ZNtc/5/

Comment: OMG IT WORKED!! But I can't close the modal anymore ? :( Any fix? Also the positioning changed already.

Comment: There you go: http://jsfiddle.net/6ZNtc/7/  You'll need to modify the css to your needs. Have fun! :P